# How to update when subquery returns multiple rows (with cursor)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

```
update tac_master
   set msg = (select 'Yes,this is a 4G supportive handset.Marketing Name'||MKT_NAME||' of LTE:1800 Manufacturer#'||manufacturer 
              from tac_master)
where lte_1800='Yes';
```

Attached is table data and structure[Table sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfpK6.png)

Comment: Why the select at all? What are you trying to do? It seems to me you just want: `update tac_master set msg = 'Yes,this is a 4G supportive handset.Marketing Name'||MKT_NAME||' of LTE:1800 Manufacturer#'||manufacturer where lte_1800='Yes';` but with the information given this is impossible to answer

Answer (score 0):

As for the code you specified, just change the subquery to value as you are updating it with constant value - you dont't need to query it again to get the mkt_name and manufacturer values as they're available in update statement:

```
update tac_master
set msg = 'Yes,this is a 4G supportive handset.Marketing Name'||MKT_NAME||' of LTE:1800 Manufacturer#'||manufacturer
where lte_1800='Yes';
```

as for general question with updating a row while subquery is returning multiple values - you can't, that's why you get this error, Oracle has to know with which value the current has to be modified and by doing it your way you're not defining it